# separate data into columns given by another column in tidyr

Tags: r, tidyr

I am tidying data in which the desired column name mapping is given in a separate column, like so:

```
df <- data.frame(splitme = c("6, 7, 8, 9", "1,2,3"), 
                 type = c("A, B, C, D", "A, C, D"))
```

df looks like:

```
     splitme       type
 6, 7, 8, 9       A, B, C, D
      1,2,3       A, C, D
```

The desired output should look like:

```
desired_output <- data.frame(A = c(6,1), 
                             B = c(7, NA), 
                             C = c(8,2), 
                             D = c(9,3))
```

i.e.:

```
  A  B C D
  6  7 8 9
  1 NA 2 3
```

If it were not for the fact that some rows have missing types, this would be a straight-forward task for `tidyr::separate`.

```
## Not correctly aligned
df %>% 
tidyr::separate(splitme, into = c("A", "B", "C", "D")) %>% 
select(-type)
```

but clearly the alignment poses issues.  If only the `into` argument could take a column specifying the split rule.  Perhaps there is a `purr::pmap_df` based strategy that could be used here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `separate_rows` followed by a reshape with `spread`:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr);
df %>% 
    # add a row identification number for reshaping purpose
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    separate_rows(splitme, type) %>% 
    spread(type, splitme) %>% 
    select(-rn)

#  A    B C D
#1 6    7 8 9
#2 1 <NA> 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `purrr:map2_dfr`, instead of parsing the `splitme` column we use the string directly in a `data.frame` call. We name the columns and `map2_dfr` bind the rows and deals with the mising values.

```
library(purrr)
map2_dfr(df$splitme,df$type,
         ~setNames(eval(parse(text=paste0("data.frame(",.x,")"))),
                   strsplit(.y,", ")[[1]]))
#   A  B C D
# 1 6  7 8 9
# 2 1 NA 2 3
```

Comment: Nice, that's what I first thought of as well. though I think you can avoid the `eval`/`parse`; I did:   `pmap_dfr(df, function(splitme, type){ as_tibble(setNames(as.list(strsplit(splitme, ", ")[[1]]), strsplit(type, ", ")[[1]]))})`.  But `separate_rows` is nicer.

Comment: Yes of course, but I don't think eval parse is bad practice here, as we have code stored in characters to begin with